# How to find line number or page number using Lucene

Tags: lucene

Can anyone help me?

For my project i use lucene for indexing files. It only give me the file name and location not mention about the line number and page number.

If it is possible with Lucene to find line number or page number? Please Help me how to do it.

Comment: Line number or page number of what? Could you add some information to your question please?

Comment: Page number of the resultant document that the keyword was found.

Comment: Could you post the actual code you're using?

Comment: Actually i am running the lucene jar file in command prompt. It's only giving the file location that the search keyword is present.I want to know if it is possible to find the page number of the searched keyword with lucene search.

Comment: See my answer regarding page #s in Lucene.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being too long for a comment so I just made it an answer.

Are you thinking of grep (*nix tool) output where you grep a set of documents and get a result set that contains matches with a line number and text? EG:

```
46: I saw the brown fox jumping over the lazy dog
```

If so, Lucene doesn't work like that. On the OS, grep, to simplify, opens each document serially and runs your specified pattern against each line of the contents inside each document. Hence, it can then produce output like the stuff I listed earlier because it's working on the file as it exists on the machine. Lucene behaves differently.

When you index a file with Lucene, Lucene creates a [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) combining the contents of each document into a highly efficient structure that lets you quickly look up and find documents containing specific pieces of information. In turn, when you run a query against the Lucene Inverted Index, it will return its internal representation of all the documents that matched your query as well as a relevancy score to provide some indication of how useful a document might be to you, based on the query. It does this by operating against it's own internal inverted index structure, not iterating over all the files in place like grep. Lucene possesses no knowledge of line or page numbers, so no, it's not possible to replicate grep with Lucene right out of the box.

Comment: Newer Lucene does support line numbers and page numbers